# FRITZ!WLAN USB Stick N v2 under ubuntu 14.10 possible?

Tags: wireless, usb, kernel, 14.10

Edit April 7, 2015: Meanwhile I installed  a mainline kernel, which works fine most of the time. After suspends, however, it often fails to reconnect, also, the number of failures increases if I install mtptools and mtpfs, which are useful for communication with android devices. It seems I have to choose.

Is my stick (lsusb output: `ID 057c:8501 AVM GmbH`) supposed to work under 14.10 with kernel 3.16.0-31-generic?

The (German) [WLAN cards wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/WLAN/Karten/AVM) seems to say it should, but it doesn't.

It loads the driver rt2800usb:

```
usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb
```

loads firmware:

```
 rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
kernel: [17398.793480] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29
kernel: [17398.794281] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_write_firmware: Info - Firmware loading not required - NIC in AutoRun mode
```

and gets lost in the authentication attempt:

```
wlan1: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
```

At this point it keeps asking for the WPA password (yes, it is the correct password) again and again and again...

The router is a FRITZ!Box 3270 and connects OK with an old Netgear stick (which, however, usually stops working after 5 or 10 minutes).